# How to efficiently add or multiply every Nth element of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy array.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**Question** Is there a quick way to multiply or add every nth element in A to yield the following arrays?

```
B = [3*1, 2*4, 3*5, 4*6]
C = [3+1, 2+4, 3+5, 4+6]
```

I can accomplish this by rolling A and then adding or multiplying it to the original A.

```
T = np.roll(A,-2)
B = (A*T)[0:4]
C = (A*T)[0:4]
```

Just wondering if there is a more pythonic/efficient way to accomplish this? I have also looked at np.add.reduceat and np.multiply.reduceat but they do not seem to allow for skipping values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
k = 2
B = A[:-k]
C = A[k:]
print(B * C)
print(B + C)
```

**Output**

```
[ 3  8 15 24]
[ 4  6  8 10]
```

Cheers.

Comment: Using negative indices `B =` can be simplified to `B = A[:-k]`.